# How to write a dictionary with nested lists to a csv and create a new row for each nested value

Tags: python-3.x, list, csv, dictionary, nested-lists

So, I have scraped data that includes Cities and Neighborhoods. The result is a dictionary of keys that are cities and list values are lists of neighborhoods. For example (Alachua - city, 161st & 110th Street and 94th Avenue are neighborhoods):

> {'Alachua': ['161st & 110th Street', '78th Ave / NW 218 St', '94th Avenue', 'Brandon Estates', 'Clarkes Addn', 'Dogwood Acres', 'Heritage Oaks', 'Hunter Woods', 'Meadowglen', 'Newnansville', 'NW 120th Pl', 'NW 140th St', 'NW 147th Ave', 'Oak Ridge at High Springs', 'Pioneer Ridge', 'Shaw Farms', 'Turkey Creek', 'Woodland Oaks'], 'Alford': ['Compass Lake in The Hills'], 'Altamonte Springs': ['Academy Cove', 'Academy Oaks', 'Altamone Springs', 'Altamonte Heights', 'Altamonte  Mall', 'Altamonte Springs', 'Apple Valley', 'Barclay Woods', 'Bay Pointe', 'Brantley Estates', 'Brantley Terrace', 'Brookhollow', 'Bunnell/Eden Park', 'Camden Club', 'Capistrano Condo', 'Corniche Townhomes ', 'Country Creek', 'Cranes Roost', 'Crescent Place', 'Emerson Plaza', 'Enclave at Altamonte', 'Escondido', 'Fern Park', 'Forest City', 'Forest Slope', 'Glen Arden Heights', 'Hailey Walk', 'Hermits Cove/ Alt. Oaks', 'Hidden Ridge', 'Hidden Spring', 'High Ridge', 'James town', 'Kensington Park', 'La Floresta', 'Lake Brantley', 'Lake Harriet Estates', 'Lake Orienta Hills', 'Lakewood', 'La Mar', 'Longwood', 'Lotus Landing', 'Lotus Vista Condominium', 'Lynchfield', 'Montgomery Square Townhomes', 'Northlake-Lilac', 'Northwood', 'Oak Harbour Condos', 'Oakland Estates', 'Oakland Hills', 'Oasis at Pearl Lake', 'Orienta Gardens', 'Ramblewood', 'Raymond Avenue South', 'River Edge', 'River Run', 'Sandy Cove', 'Sanlando', 'San Sebastian Heights', 'South Apopka', 'Spring Oaks', 'Springs Colony', 'Spring Valley', 'Sutton Place Townhomes', 'The Landings', 'Timberlake', 'Villa Brantley', 'Village', "Waterside Crane's Roost", 'Wekiva Bend', 'Westridge Centre', 'Wymore Grove'], 'Altha': ['Altha Outskirts'], 'Altoona': ['Camp Ocala', 'E Deer Rd', 'Mattison Lane', 'North Altoona', 'The Meadows'], 'Alva': ['Alva', 'River Hall', 'Wellington'], 'Anthony': ['Sparr'], 'Apalachicola': ['Bluff Road', 'Historic 98']}

I want my output to be a csv in the following format:

> City, Neighborhood

> Alachua, 161st & 110th Street

> Alachua, 94th Avenue
> ...

So, I want to create a new row for every value from the list of neighborhoods and keep the city name in the city column. I have searched a lot of questions here on stackoverflow and other websites and can't seem to find this kind of issue. There are various approaches but none of them matches the desired output.

The following, for example, takes city as a column header and lists neighborhoods in these columns but I am not searching for that.

```
import itertools

keys = neighborhoods_dict.keys()
csvrows = itertools.zip_longest(*[neighborhoods_dict[k] for k in keys], fillvalue='dummy')

with open('out.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=';',
                            quotechar='\\', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    csvwriter.writerow(keys)
    for row in csvrows:
        csvwriter.writerow(row)
```

Any help is appreciated, I have been running in circles.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I managed to accomplish the task with:

```
with open('try.csv', 'w') as file:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(file)
    csvwriter.writerow(["City", "Neighborhood"])
    for key, values in neighborhoods_dict.items():
        for value in values:
#             print(key, value)
            row = key, value
            print(row)
            csvwriter.writerow(row)
```

It was actually quite simple, I just needed to sit down and breathe deeply and the solution came.

Answer (score 0):

Comments inside the code

```
import json
import csv

#Function that takes two arguments string names of the files
def createCSV(file_json,file_csv):
#Open the data.json to fetch the data
    with open(file_json) as file:
        data = json.load(file)
#Create and open data.csv file to write 'w'    
    with open(file_csv, "w") as file:
        csv_file = csv.writer(file)
#Cre the first row names of the csv
        csv_file.writerow(["City","Neighborhood "])
#Iterate the data to write them into csv file
        for item in data:
            for z in data[item]:
                csv_file.writerow([item,z])
                
createCSV('data.json','data.csv')
```